# Expanding a power series at a different point

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f(z)=\sum_na_nz^n$ be a complex power series with convergence radius $R$, I want to show the function $f$ is analytic, i.e. can be expanded to a power series on a neighbourhood of any point in its domain (I know this can be done with Cauchy's integral formula, but I'm looking for an elementary derivation of this fact).

To that end let $w\in U_R(0)$, I want to show $f$ can be written as $\sum_kb_k(z-w)^k$ for $z\in U_{R-|w|}(w)\subset U_R(0)$ and some $b_k$. Since $z\in U_R(0)$, the series $\sum_na_nz^n$ converges absolutely. Writing $z^n=(z-w+w)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(z-w)^jw^{n-j}$ we get a new series
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^na_n\binom njw^{n-j}(z-w)^j$$
whose $m$-th partial sum is $\sum_{n=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^na_n\binom njw^{n-j}(z-w)^j=\sum_{j=0}^m(z-w)^j\sum_{n=j}^ma_n\binom nj w^{n-j}$.

How then do I rejig this last expression to get coefficients $b_k$ so that $f(z)=\sum_kb_k(z-w)^k$? Please be as explicit and thorough as possible.

Comment: You already did, except for letting now $m\to\infty$.

Comment: But how am I justified in letting $m\to\infty$ and what does it mean for the double sum $\sum_{j=0}^m(z-w)^j\sum_{n=j}^ma_n\binom nj w^{n-j}$?

Comment: The inner sums become series, which (absolute) convergence you can test with the root  or ratio test. Use that the ration/root test for the $a_n$ gives radius $R$ and that $|w|<s<R$, for some $0<s$. The sums of those series are the $b_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add just one further step to OPs derivation. Expanding $f$ at a point $w$ which is in the interior of $U_R(0)$, the disc of convergence of $f$ at $0$ with radius $R$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-w+w)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}w^{n-j}(z-w)^j\tag{1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\underbrace{\left(\sum_{n=j}^{\infty}\binom{n}{j}a_nw^{n-j}\right)}_{b_j}(z-w)^j}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

We get (2) by *rearrangement* of the finite inner sums from (1). We can justify this rearrangement without using Cauchy's integral formula. We instead recall that an *absolutely convergent* series can be divided up into *infinitely many infinite subseries*, the sum of which coincides with the sum of the original series.

We show the sum coincides with the sum of the original series by looking at the Taylor expansion of $f$ at the point $z=w$:
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(j)}(w)}{j!}(z-w)^j\tag{3}
\end{align*}

The coefficient of the series in (3) is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{f^{(j)}(w)}{j!}}&=
\frac{1}{j!}\left.\left(\frac{d^j}{dz^j}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n\right)\right|_{z=w}\\
&=\frac{1}{j!}\left.\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n n(n-1)\cdots (n-j+1)z^{n-j}\right|_{z=w}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=j}^{\infty}\binom{n}{j}a_nw^{n-j}}
\end{align*}
Since this is also the coefficient $b_j$ in (2) the representation (2) is justified.

---

**Note:** With respect to a comment from OP: The above statement that

- an *absolutely convergent* series can be divided up into *infinitely many infinite subseries*, the sum of which coincides with the sum of the original series

is shown for instance in *[Theory and Applications of Infinite Series](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/theory-and-application-of-infinite-series)* by K. Knopp. In chapter 3, section 16: *Absolute convergence. Derangement of Series* the author proves this property of absolutely convergent series in two steps:

- In Theorem 3 he shows that if $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then every *sub-series* $\sum a_{\lambda_n}$ - for which the indices $\lambda_n$ denote any strictly monotone increasing sequence of positive integers, is again absolutely convergent.
- In Theorem 4 he shows that

  - picking out *sub-series* of this kind (finite or infinite many) such that  each element of the original series has been selected precisely once
  - then rearranging the elements of each sub-series in any order
  - then rearranging the *sub-series* in any order
  - then summing up everything gives the same value as the original series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up completing the proof via $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty |z_{m,n}|<\infty\implies\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_{m,n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty z_{m,n}$, which as I understand it can be proved with Fubini. "recall that an absolutely convergent series can be divided up into infinitely many infinite subseries, the sum of which coincides with the sum of the original series.", how do you prove this? Because atm I'm struggling with a similar question on series, namely the Euler product formula, cont'd below.

Comment: I'm trying to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^s}=\prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ for $Re(s)>1$. When considering the product for $p\leq N$, e.g. for two primes $p,q$, using the Cauchy product formula we get $\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-q^{-s}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^m\frac1{(p^nq^{m-n})^{s}}$, so by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic every $n$ whose prime factors come from $\{p,q\}$ appears in exactly one term of this series once. My problem is how do I justify "expanding the brackets" and simply writing this as $\sum_{P(n)\subset\{p,q\}}\frac1{n^s}$, which relates to what you mention

Comment: @V.Ch.: You're welcome. I've added a note which might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum and reference!

Comment: @V.Ch.: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If $(a_k)_{k \geq 0}$ is a sequence of complex numbers we may form an associated sequence of polynomials $(f_n)_{n \geq 0}$ where $p_n (z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kz^k$, and define
$$
D = \{ z\in \mathbb C: (p_(z))_{n\geq 0} \text{ converges as } n \to \infty\}
$$

Then there is a unique $R\in [0,\infty]$ such that $B(0,R)\subseteq D\subseteq \bar{B}(0,R)$, and $(a_k)_{k \geq 0}$ defines a function $f\colon D\to \mathbb C$ given by $f(z) = \lim_{n\to \infty} p_n(z)$, where this is conventionally written as $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$, and this description of $f$ is said to be expressing $f$ as power series centred at $0$.

The OP asked for an "elementary proof" that, for any $w \in B(0,R)$, we may write $f(z)$ as a power series centred at $w$ in a neighbourhood $U$ of $z_0\in B(0,R)$. More precisely, there should be a sequence $(b_k)$ with the property that $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k$ for $z \in B(z_0, R-|z_0|)$.

Now if $w = z-z_0$ then $p_n(z) = q_n(w)$ for $q_n(w) = \sum_{k=0}^n b^n_kw^k$, where
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
q_n(w) &= \sum_{k=0}^n b^n_k w^k = \sum_{l=0}^n a_l(w+z_0)^l = \sum_{l=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^l \binom{l}{k}a_lz_0^{l-k}.w^k \\ &=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{l=k}^n \binom{l}{k}a_l z_0^{l-k}\right)w^k
\end{split}
\tag{$\dagger$}
\end{equation}

Now clearly $q_n(w) = p_n(z) \to f(z)$ as $n \to \infty$, but the coefficients $b^n_k$ of the polynomials $q_n$ all vary with $n$ (unlike for $p_n(z)$ where the coefficient of $z^k$ is always equal to $a_k$ once $n \geq k$) so we cannot immediately conclude that
$$
f(z) = \lim_{n \to \infty}(\sum_{k=0}^n (\lim_{m\to \infty} b^m_k).w^k).
$$
However, this is exactly what the strong version of rearrangement of absolutely convergent series -- that is, that the limit of an absolutely convergent series remains the limit if we sum the series as a sum of infinitely many subseries -- ensures, one just has to take care to specify which series one applies this to. Let $T$ be the countable set given by
$$
T = \{(k,l) \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\times \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}: k\leq l\}
$$
and let $c_{k,l} = a_l\binom{l}{k}z_0^{l-k}w^k$. Then if $r=|z_0|+|w|<R$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{(k,l) \in T: l\leq n}|c_{k,l}| &= \sum_{l=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{l}{k}|a_l||z_0|^{l-k}|w|^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n |a_l|(|z_0|+|w|)^l <\sum_{l=0}^\infty |a_l|r^l<\infty
\end{split}
$$
and since $\sum_{l=0}^\infty |a_l|r^l$ is independent of $n$, it follows $\sum_{(k,l)\in T} |c_{k,l}|<\infty$ and hence the series $\sum_{(k,l)\in T} c_{k,l}$ is absolutely convergent.

Now letting $n\to \infty$ in ($\dagger$) shows that $f(z) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^l c_{k,l} = \sum_{(k,l)\in T} c_{k,l}$, hence by the rearrangement result
$$
\sum_{(k,l)\in T} c_{k,l} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=k}^\infty c_{k,l} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{l=k}^\infty a_l\binom{l}{k}z_0^{l-k}\right)w^k,
$$
and thus if $b_k = \sum_{l=k}^\infty a_l\binom{l}{k}z_0^{l-k}$, we see that $b_k$ is the limit of an absolutely convergent series and $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kw^k$ in $B(z_0,R-|z_0|)$, that is, $f(z)$ can be expressed as a power series centred at $w$ as required.

epi163sqrt's answer (though I may be misunderstanding it) shows that $f(z)$ can be expressed as a power series by using the theorem that the derivative of a power series is given by the termwise differentiation to show that $\frac{f^{(j)}(z_0)}{j!} = \sum_{n=j}^\infty \binom{n}{j}a_n z_0^n$, and then that $(2)$ holds using the Taylor expansion of $f$. Using rearrangement of the series $\sum_{T} c_{k,l}$ we have shown that $(2)$ holds, and thus combining $(2)$ with the theorem on differentiating power series one obtains a proof that a power series is equal to its Taylor expansion about any point in $B(0,R)$.